# Saving a response with the submit button (html)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

2 weeks ago I taught myself html, css and javascript in my spare time. I know the basics of all three of these languages. I just need a little help with the submit button and server side programming.

Here's my problem:

I made a website (html & css) that randomly generates two things to rate (for example, girls). Under these, there is a radio button for left or right. Then under that there is a submit button. When you enter left or right and hit submit, there is no rating algorithm, so it just goes to the next file (which repeats this). I want to know how to put in a rating algorithm to keep score (like elo or a rating/10). How should I approach this? I thought of a couple of ways, but I don't know if I can pull it off in JS or I'll have to learn php.

For JS, the only idea I have is maybe making and if/else if. For example:

If girl1 and girl2 are available and girl1 is chosen:

Run this algorithm.

Else if girl1 and girl2 are available and girl2 is chosen:

Run this algorithm.

If I do this, will the variables change and be saved when anybody uses the site, or are there limits?

I will also be using a web hosting service, I don't have my own server.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: You need a server side programming language to do it. PHP is easy. Lemme post a small conceptual model

Answer (score 0):

This is the form that you would use for selection. Lets say a file named `abc.php`

Write a bit of html in `abc.php`

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="radio" name="person" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="person" value="2" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

This is the server side scripting

And a bit of php in `abc.php`

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $person = $_POST['person'];
        echo $person;
    }

?>
```

This `$person` has now the value either `1` or `2`. Since you have gotten the value now you can use it. for instance

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $person = $_POST['person'];
        echo $person;

        ratePerson($person);
    }

    function ratePerson($person)
    {
        //some logic of your algorithm
    }
?>
```

Comment: How would I encorporate this into the html file?

Comment: You don't have to use `.html` file. Just use any file with `.php` extension. for example `abc.php`

Comment: You can use `wampserver64` to initiate it locally. Like `localhost:8080/abc.php`

Comment: In php file you can have your `html` and `php` code both!